# Rails: Calling Model methods in to_json(:methods => [:model_method])

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord

I've defined two methods in Model `image_url` & `thumb_url`to get absolute `url` of images and thumbs
and calling them in controller `.to_json()` method.

when I view the `Json` response it only shows `image_url` not the `thumb_url`
please guide me what I am doing wrong here.

**Model :**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

    validates :image, presence: true

      has_attached_file :image, styles: { :medium => "640x", thumb: "100x100#" } # # means crop the image
        validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  def image_url
   relative_path =  image.url(:medium)
   self.add_host_prefix relative_path
  end

 def thumb_url
   relative_path = image.url(:thumb)
   self.add_host_prefix relative_path
 end

  def add_host_prefix(url)
    URI.join(root_url, url).to_s
  end
end
```

**controller :**

```
class Api::ImagesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @posts =  Post.all.order(id: :desc)
    paginated_records = @posts.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => params[:per_page])
    @posts = with_pagination_info( paginated_records )
    render :json => @posts.to_json(:methods => [:thumb_url], :methods =>[:image_url])
  end
end
```

**here is My Json Response:**

```
"data": [{
"id": 23,
"caption": "World Top View",
"created_at": "2015-09-17T14:10:57.278Z",
"updated_at": "2015-09-17T14:10:57.278Z",
"image_file_name": "world.topo.bathy.200401.3x21600x10800.jpg",
"image_content_type": "image/jpeg",
"image_file_size": 29698041,
"image_updated_at": "2015-09-17T14:10:36.975Z",
"image_url": "http://localhost:3000/system/posts/images/000/000/023/medium/world.topo.bathy.200401.3x21600x10800.jpg?1442499036"}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't pass two `:methods` keys into the hash, only the last key will be used. Remember that a key for a hash has to be unique.  If you want mulitiple methods, you should do...

```
render :json => @posts.to_json(:methods => [:thumb_url, :image_url])
```